# Circuits for general computing

Tags: complexity

In TCS, functions need to be converted into boolean circuits.

So is this Boolean circuit a combinational logic, i.e. a directed acyclic graph, satisfying the topological order?

I would appreciate your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loop *can* be transformed into a circuit. The circuit might be bigger, but any polynomial-time program you can think of can be converted into a polynomial-size boolean circuit. Garbled circuits capture general two-party computation and is not limited to a restricted set of functions.

Comment: Yeah, that is more accurate.

Comment: Hi! Can we compile these `loop` into cyclic combinational circuits?

Comment: What is a cyclic combinational circuit?

Answer (score 1):

We have to think about the cost of realizing a specific kind of [circuit complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_complexity).

We can say that a general program executing some kind of interactive command can't be converted in a feasible circuit: think about a  `main() { while(true) {} }`.

An interesting discussion can be read here [Conditional Boolean circuits](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/102857/conditional-boolean-circuits?rq=1)